# Sending data before saving Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this function with a Post that I want to insert the data in the database (MongoDB). First of all, I want to save the data in the model "Recetas" and after in the model "Users". And finally send the response. My problem is that is not saving in the model Users and is sending the data before saving.

This is my code

```
addReceta = function (req, res) {

        User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
            if (!user){
                res.send(404, 'User not found');
            }
            else{
                fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
                    var id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
                    var newPath = pwd + id +req.files.file.originalFilename;
                        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
                            var date_created = new Date();
                            var date  = date_created.toISOString().slice(0,10);
                            var receta = new Receta({
                                Titulo:  datos2.titulo,
                                Username:  datos2.username,
                                Ingredientes:  datos2.ingredientes,
                                Dificultad:  datos2.dificultad,
                                Descripción: datos2.descripcion,
                                Personas:  datos2.personas,
                                Date_Created: date_created,
                                Tiempo:  datos2.tiempo,
                                user_id: req.params.id,
                                imageUrl: URL + id + req.files.file.originalFilename
                            })
                            receta.save(function(err) {
                                if(!err) {
                                    console.log('Created in Receta');
                                } 
                                else {
                                    console.log(error);
                                }
                            });
                            var UserReceta = ({
                                _id: receta._id,
                                Titulo : receta.Titulo,
                                Username : receta.Username,
                                Descripción : receta.Descripción,
                                Ingredientes : receta.Ingredientes,
                                Dificultad : receta.Dificultad,
                                Personas : receta.Personas,
                                Date_Created: date_created,
                                Tiempo : receta.Tiempo,
                                user_id : receta.user_id,
                                imageUrl: receta.imageUrl
                            });
                            user.Recetas.push(UserReceta);
                            user.save(function (err){
                                if (!err) {
                                    console.log('Created in User Recetas');
                                } 
                                else {
                                    res.send(500, err);
                                }
                            });
                            res.send(receta);
                        });
                });
            };
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `res.send(receta);` inside the callback after saving in Users, right after the console.log:

```
console.log('Created in User Recetas');
res.send(receta);
```